# Google Location on Genymotion

Tags: android, geolocation, google-play-services, genymotion

I tried Google Play Service tutorial on how to get user last location.
The code is actually work on my Device but it is not working on Genymotion.
I have installed google play service and also turned on GPS and location on the genymotion.

I also check using the code below and it return 0, which means google play service is available

```
GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
```

So what else do I need? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: you can select target api as google api. It support maps I have also tried it & it successfully running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by installing Google Play Services in Genymotion Emulator by downloading [gapps-jb-20130812-signed.zip](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=23060877490000128). and after that simply Drag & Drop this file to Genymotion emulator so it will start installing in it.
After Installing, just restart the Genymotion Emulator.
And then you can run your Google Map project in Genymotion.

**P.S.** Dont forgot to set target platform as Google API.
To do this by right click on Project Property **>** go to Android Menu from Leftside Panel  **>**  then Select targeted Google API platform.